# Finding the area (Probability) under a non parametric PDF

Tags: probability, probability-density

How would i go about calculating the area (Probability) betweeen 2 points under a non parametric PDF for a given set of x and y data?

Is there a package in python/scipy/statsmodels that allows me to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Cheers

```
x = array([443, 444, 445, 446, 447, 448, 449, 450, 451, 452, 453, 454, 455,
       456, 457, 458, 459, 460, 461, 462, 463, 464, 465, 466])

y = array([1.42108547e-13, 1.38555834e-11, 1.10391341e-09, 4.44788527e-08,
       1.57671946e-06, 3.56957957e-05, 5.07987711e-04, 4.50095500e-03,
       2.47811094e-02, 8.53820383e-02, 1.86555694e-01, 2.61763533e-01,
       2.36928044e-01, 1.37248060e-01, 4.98071050e-02, 1.09658321e-02,
       1.41422995e-03, 1.03744795e-04, 4.25019397e-06, 9.66796303e-08,
       1.22804049e-09, 8.82441617e-12, 3.63136435e-14, 1.70842985e-16])
```

Comment: What are x and y? Do you need a bivariate distributions for those, or are the y-values some frequencies? Do you want to consider x as discrete or continuous?

Comment: The y-values are frequencies and x is discrete. Thanks